# Joomla! URL Rewrite creates 404 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have a problem with my joomla and the URL Rewrite function. 
I have activated this function in backend and renamed the htaccess.txt to .htaccess.
But now I get a 404 error on every menu link.

You can find the site here: (removed after solution found)

I used the standard htaccess file.

I already checked - mo_rewrite is active.

I also have added a image where you can see the system information.
[image]

Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with RewriteRule settings in .htaccess. It setup to use root of server path, but your site is in directory.

For example:
http://www.skripten.at/joom25/index.php/studium-sp-481533707/finanzen-soziales

this URL works.

Try to change in .htaccess the line above or copy your site to the DocumentRoot without subfolder:

```
RewriteBase /joom25/
```

and in Joomla config find and change:

```
var $live_site = 'http://www.skripten.at/joom25/';
```

May be you need some more changes, it's what about i think in a first step.

Answer (score 0):

It might be even more simple, at least for me it was :D
I took a look at the following article [Friendly Urls](http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_%28SEF%29_URLs) and since I am on a hosted server I was almost sure that mod_rewrite was ok, so I just renamed the htaccess.txt to .htaccess, then went to the global configuration (in site) turned on the friendly url and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem too. But the solution is not too far. Just go to you file manager and rename your htaccess.txt to  .htaccess    Remember! dont forget to put dot (.) in front of htaccess   like this ( .htaccess)   that is all you need.